# Jackson ObjectMapper not accepting all dateFormats

Tags: java, json, simpledateformat, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I am trying to set a custom date Format to the Jackson Object mapper(I am using ***Jackson-databind-2.8.x***) so that it can parse the incoming JSON date in a specific format. A date format without seconds part works fine, but when i add seconds to it ; it seems to fail.

**Format that works**

Date format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ`

Example of date that gets parsed fine :  2019-09-01 15:00+0000

Setting date format to object mapper:

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ"));
```

**Format that does not work**

Date format : `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`

Example date : 2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000

Setting date format to object mapper:

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"));
```

Exception :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000': Unparseable date: "2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000")
```

I have verified that above is a proper simple date format as below code works fine:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TestDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");

        String date = "2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000";

        System.out.println(format.parse(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: Added the same now. Had missed adding this earlier.

Comment: I've checked this for version `2.8.0` and it works as expected. Could you show also your `POJO` and `JSON` payload?

Answer (score 1):

You should look more closely at your code:

`objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ"));`

vs

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");`

Which are two different formats.

Should be:

`objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"));`

Note the addition for **:ss**

which is indeed the format for the given String.

**EDIT**

This test works (using Jackson 2.8.0)

```
public class FormatTest {

    @Test
    public void testFormat() throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
        String date = "2019-09-01 15:00:00+0000";
        Date parse = sdf.parse(date);
        String json = "{\"date\" : \"" + date + "\"}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
        ClassWithDate cwd = objectMapper.readValue(json, ClassWithDate.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(parse, cwd.date);
    }

    private static class ClassWithDate {
        public Date date;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just updated my question to be more clear. There are two parts 1) where i show which format works & which does not 2) A simple Date parsing code which uses the format that does not work.